# Get subscribers with most opens in campaign report Mailchimp

Tags: python, mailchimp

How we can get subscribers with most opens in campaign report Mailchimp by **mailchimp3** package python ?

So far, I use the class `reports.email_activity` to take the number of open, then I make filter, but this way it's so long with large database.

Comment: Have you looked at Batch operations? I am also working something similar which needs access to email activity. Batch operations work a bit better. Let me know how it goes or if you have found a better option.

Comment: Yes, I run in the batch operation the command like that : `client.reports.email_activity.get(campaign_id='yourCampaignId', subscriber_hash='email_we_want_to_track@mail.com') `, and this words a bit better. On the other hand, I could do it by create a segment in the contact list ;)